# Custom Title bar delay

Tags: android, styles, delay, titlebar

My app uses a custom titlebar created as a layout and is implemented using this format:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE, R.layout.my_custom_title);
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

Now it did not work using the regular theme `android:Theme.Light`, neither did `android:Theme.Light.NoTitleBar`, they both resulted in a fatal exception when `setContentView` was called. So I created a custom style which looks like this:

```
<style name="MyWindowTitleBackground">
    <item name="android:background">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name="CustomTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light">
    <item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/MyWindowTitleBackground</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">false</item>
    <item name ="android:windowTitleSize">35dip</item>
</style>
```

However, every time the app is started there is a small delay in between the start and display of the actual layout with the custom titlebar, in this delay the default titlebar is shown with the appname in it. After about a second, when the Oncreate finishes, the custom title is loaded and shown.

Is there any way to fix this? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is no way. Its an annoying bug. Try the official skype app, you'll see it has the same issue.

Comment: If there would've been no way, every app with a custom title should have this bug.. The Dropbox app, for example, does not show this behaviour.

Comment: In my dropbox application there is no title. Can you give a SS of your title bar with title?

Answer (score 1):

Try putting

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
```

before the other lines and see if that works.

and putting

```
setContentView(R.layout.my_layout);
```

last.  I seemed to remember my app crashing because I had it in the wrong order.

Comment: This does not work.. I didn't see any difference when putting super.onCreate(..) on different places. placing the SetContentView after the getWindow().. results in nullpointers in various places, when calling findViewById().